# java NIO.2 glob problem

Tags: java, nio

I have:

```
Path path = Paths.get("Foo.class");
Path path2 = Paths.get("Foo.java");

FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
PathMatcher matcher = fs.getPathMatcher("glob:*.{class, java}"); 

matcher.matches(path); // TRUE
matcher.matches(path_2); // FALSE
```

Why `path2` is false if the glob syntax {} means that it matches .class or .java?

From jdk [documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29):

***.{java,class}    Matches file names ending with .java or .class**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of the space in `class, java`